# How to display a command name

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a "Command not found" error when someone is trying to execute a command that is not exist.
Here's my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):
        команда_не_найдена = discord.Embed(
            title=':question:Команда не найдена:question:',
            description=f'{ctx.author.mention}, command **"{commandnamehere}"** not found.'
            )
        await ctx.send(embed=команда_не_найдена)
        raise error
```

Comment: It looks like you might get that information out of the `ctx` parameter.  Look at the third example on this page: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107230/discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass `error`.

```
description=f'{ctx.author.mention}, **{error}**.'
```

When `CommandNotFound` is raised, the message returned is: `Command "RandomCommand" is not found`